# How can I align vertically/on top tikz pictures (circuitikz) in minipage/figure/tabular environment?

Tags: latex, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align vertically this 3 circuits. I would like to align the on top, instead of bottom part (they automatically align bottom with that code)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
    \centering
    \Large
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw[]
  (0,3) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_0}$,o-] (2,3) -- (2,4)
  to [C, l=$\mathbf{Q_{1}}$] (6,4) -- (6,3)
  to [short, -o] (7,3)
  (2,3) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_1}$] (6,2) -- (6,3); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    } & 
    \scalebox{0.5}{
     \begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw[]
  (0,4) to [R, l=$R_0$,o-] (2,4) -- (2,5)
  to [C, l=$Q_{1}$] (8,5) -- (8,4)
  to [short, -o] (9,4)
  (2,4) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$R_1$] (4,2) -- (4,3)
  to [C, l=$Q_{2}$] (8,3)
  (4,2) -- (4,1) to [R, l=$R_2$] (8,1) -- (8,4); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    } & 
    \scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{circuitikz}[]
  \draw[]
  (0,4) to [R, l=$R_0$,o-] (2,4) -- (2,5)
  to [C, l=$Q_{1}$] (9,5) -- (9,4)
  to [short, -o] (10,4)
  (2,4) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$R_1$] (4,2) -- (4,3)
  to [C, l=$Q_{2}$] (9,3)
  (4,2) -- (4,0) to [R, l=$R_2$] (6,0) -- (6,1)
  to [R, l=$R_3$] (9,1)
  (6,0) -- (6,-1) to [C, l=$Q_{3}$] (9,-1) -- (9,4); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    }\\ 
    \small(a) Randles & \small(b) 2 TC & \small(b) 3 TC
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-3pt}    
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,font=small}
    \caption{description}
    \label{fig:circuits}
\end{figure}
```

I would like the three circuits to be aligned on the top part. Also, if possible, to know how to align the at the same 'pole' height. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `baseline` option from `tikz` to change the alignment. For example to get the images top aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
    \centering
    \Large
    \begin{tblr}{Q[c,t]Q[c,t]Q[c,t]}
    \scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
  \draw[]
  (0,3) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_0}$,o-] (2,3) -- (2,4)
  to [C, l=$\mathbf{Q_{1}}$] (6,4) -- (6,3)
  to [short, -o] (7,3)
  (2,3) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$\mathbf{R_1}$] (6,2) -- (6,3); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    } & 
    \scalebox{0.5}{
     \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
  \draw[]
  (0,4) to [R, l=$R_0$,o-] (2,4) -- (2,5)
  to [C, l=$Q_{1}$] (8,5) -- (8,4)
  to [short, -o] (9,4)
  (2,4) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$R_1$] (4,2) -- (4,3)
  to [C, l=$Q_{2}$] (8,3)
  (4,2) -- (4,1) to [R, l=$R_2$] (8,1) -- (8,4); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    } & 
    \scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
  \draw[]
  (0,4) to [R, l=$R_0$,o-] (2,4) -- (2,5)
  to [C, l=$Q_{1}$] (9,5) -- (9,4)
  to [short, -o] (10,4)
  (2,4) -- (2,2) to [R, l=$R_1$] (4,2) -- (4,3)
  to [C, l=$Q_{2}$] (9,3)
  (4,2) -- (4,0) to [R, l=$R_2$] (6,0) -- (6,1)
  to [R, l=$R_3$] (9,1)
  (6,0) -- (6,-1) to [C, l=$Q_{3}$] (9,-1) -- (9,4); 
    \end{circuitikz}
    }\\ 
    \small(a) Randles & \small(b) 2 TC & \small(b) 3 TC
\end{tblr}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-3pt}    
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,font=small}
    \caption{description}
    \label{fig:circuits}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]